# How to test if a condition is null when adapting to a component.json in AEM during Junit test?

Tags: java, aem, junit5

I would like to find out if it is possible to test for the following if condition to be null for my junit test.

The following is the implementation of the AEM sightly model:

```
int currentYear = 0;

@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
     String lmStr = "";
     Calendar lm= currentPage.getLastModified();
     if(lm!=null){       <= I would like to know if it is possible to test for the null condition
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("DD_MMM_YYYY");
            lmStr = df.format(lm.getTime());
        }
        //Gets the current year for copyright
        currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

The following is the component.json file I used to adapt to this sightly model:

```
{
  "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page",
  "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
  "jcr:created": "Wed Jul 10 2019 17:28:17 GMT+0800",
  "jcr:content": {
    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:PageContent",
    "jcr:mixinTypes": [
      "mix:versionable"
    ],
    "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
    "jcr:title": "Page Title",
    "cq:lastReplicationAction": "Activate",
    "jcr:versionHistory": "ddd-eee-fff",
    "cq:template": "/conf/project/templates/some-template",
    "cq:lastReplicatedBy": "some-service",
    "jcr:predecessors": [
      "aaa-bbb-ccc"
    ],
    "jcr:created": "Wed Jul 10 2019 17:28:17 GMT+0800",
    "cq:lastReplicated": "Mon Sep 30 2019 17:37:26 GMT+0800",
    "cq:lastModified": "null",                              <= I tried putting null here instead of the date but it's not working
    "jcr:description": "Description",
...
```

I would greatly appreciate any form of help or sharing of knowledge if you have encountered the following issue previously. Thank you!

Comment: What abt mocking *currentPage*  by using mockito? https://site.mockito.org/

Comment: what do you get when the key "cq:lastModified" is removed ?

Comment: It will throw a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wcm-io-dev/1IVwFxtCWOY)
`JcrConstants.JCR_UUID, JcrConstants.JCR_BASEVERSION, JcrConstants.JCR_PREDECESSORS, JcrConstants.JCR_SUCCESSORS, JcrConstants.JCR_CREATED, JcrConstants.JCR_VERSIONHISTORY, "jcr:checkedOut", "jcr:isCheckedOut", "rep:policy"`
are all immutable